# Replacing zeros (or NANs) in a matrix with the previous element row-wise or column-wise in a fully vectorized way

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, vectorization

I need to replace the zeros (or NaNs) in a matrix with the previous element row-wise, so basically I need this Matrix X

```
[0,1,2,2,1,0;  
5,6,3,0,0,2;  
0,0,1,1,0,1]
```

To become like this:

```
[0,1,2,2,1,1;  
5,6,3,3,3,2;  
0,0,1,1,1,1],
```

please note that if the first row element is zero it will stay like that.

I know that this has been solved for a single row or column vector  in a vectorized way and this is one of the nicest way of doing that:

```
id = find(X);         
X(id(2:end)) = diff(X(id));       
Y = cumsum(X)
```

The problem is that the indexing of a matrix in Matlab/Octave  is consecutive and increments columnwise so it works for a single row or column but the same exact concept cannot be applied but needs to be modified with multiple rows 'cause each of raw/column starts fresh and must be regarded as independent. I've tried my best and googled the whole google but coukldn’t find a way out. If I apply that same very idea in a loop it gets too slow cause my matrices contain 3000 rows at least. Can anyone help me out of this please?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean on the transpose.

Comment: Yet had to edit this again to insert the case of 2 initial zeros and stress the fact that they should not inherit the previous row's last value. Sorry for the continuous editing but special cases and deeper understandings emerge as we go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified version of Eitan's answer to avoid propagating values across rows:

```
Y = X'; %'
tf = Y > 0;
tf(1,:) = true;
idx = find(tf);
Y(idx(2:end)) = diff(Y(idx));
Y = reshape(cumsum(Y(:)),fliplr(size(X)))';
```

Comment: Apparently, that's just what I did (haven't noticed you posted a second solution). Keep in mind that yours is susceptible to NaNs though.

Comment: Yes a NaN (or equally an Inf or -Inf) will screw things up for cumsum. If you have values with very different magnitudes, floating point error can even be a problem. My preferred solution for this kind of thing is actually my other answer, which uses an indexing approach. This handles Infs as regular values, can be applied to non-numeric types, supports limiting fill distance etc.

Comment: That said the cumsum approach is probably a better fit for the OP.

Comment: Great, looks working with no issues to me, and it's fast: on average 0.4 secs (on my 4 years old i7) on a 3000X3000 Matrix with about 50% zeros. Thanks

Comment: @Charles I've stuck to the "`cumsum` approach" since it has been proposed by the OP in the question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

**Special case when zeros are isolated in each row**

You can do it using the two-output version of [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to locate the zeros and NaN's in all columns except the first, and then using [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to fill those entries with their row-wise preceding values:

```
[ii jj] = find( (X(:,2:end)==0) | isnan(X(:,2:end)) );
X(ii+jj*size(X,1)) = X(ii+(jj-1)*size(X,1));
```

**General case (consecutive zeros are allowed on each row)**

```
X(isnan(X)) = 0; %// handle NaN's and zeros in a unified way
aux = repmat(2.^(1:size(X,2)), size(X,1), 1) .* ...
    [ones(size(X,1),1) logical(X(:,2:end))]; %// positive powers of 2 or 0
col = floor(log2(cumsum(aux,2))); %// col index
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (col-1)*size(X,1), (1:size(X,1)).'); %'// linear index
Y = X(ind);
```

The trick is to make use of the matrix `aux`, which contains 0 if the corresponding entry of `X` is 0 and its column number is greater than 1; or else contains 2 raised to the column number. Thus, applying `cumsum` row-wise to this matrix, taking `log2` and rounding down (matrix `col`) gives the column index of the rightmost nonzero entry up to the current entry, for each row (so this is a kind of row-wise "cummulative max" function.) It only remains to convert from column number to linear index (with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html); could also be done with `sub2ind`) and use that to index `X`.

This is valid for moderate sizes of `X` only. For large sizes, the powers of 2 used by the code quickly approach `realmax` and incorrect indices result.

Example:

```
X =
     0     1     2     2     1     0     0
     5     6     3     0     0     2     3
     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
```

gives

```
>> Y
Y =
     0     1     2     2     1     1     1
     5     6     3     3     3     2     3
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks, I'm afraid my example was not proper, I fixed it now, your great code works only if there is one zero to replace but when there are more it doesn't fill the other zeros:  5,6,3,0,0,2; should become 5,6,3,3,3,2; sorry for using an inadequate example.

Comment: The solution works only for matrices up to n*1023. For 1024 or larger, `aux` contains `inf`

Comment: That's impressive Luis, there is unfortunately a Tricky problem, if i generate a Matrix like X = randint(1000,1000) so uniformly distibuted 1 and 0s it works but if I generate X = randint(1000,1000,100) so 0 is less frequent it mostly fails, and actually in ind you can find values bigger than 1000000 (1000*1000).

Comment: Damn! Daniel, you are right! aside from the issue i mentioned it gets NANs in the index when more than 1024. gosh. Looks like this is quite a Tricky one.

Comment: @DanielR True. `2^1024` is very close to `realmax`

Comment: @aldo I'm afraid that using powers of 2 means very large numbers even for moderate sizes of `X`. With such large numbers precision is lost, which causes wrong index values

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize your own solution as follows:

```
Y = X.';                                       %'// Make a transposed copy of X
Y(isnan(Y)) = 0;
idx = find([ones(1, size(X, 1)); Y(2:end, :)]);
Y(idx(2:end)) = diff(Y(idx));
Y = reshape(cumsum(Y(:)), [], size(X, 1)).';   %'// Reshape back into a matrix
```

This works by treating the input data as a long vector, applying the original solution and then reshaping the result back into a matrix. The first column is always treated as non-zero so that the values don't propagate throughout rows. Also note that the original matrix is transposed so that it is converted to a vector in row-major order.

Comment: Hi Eitan, same comment as for Louis, I possibly used an improper example, the code should fill also consecutive zeros, I corected it now, sorry and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Gotcha. Please take a look at the revised answer.

Comment: Well maybe  i figured out: it's Y!

Comment: I think a limitation with this solution is that it will propagate values across rows. eg if the first and second values in a row are zero, the second value will get the most recent non-zero value (from a different row), while the first gets explicitly restored to zero.

Comment: @Charles Yep, it has this exact problem. Thanks for showing that, I have been too enthusiastic.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @aldo Yes, it's Y (was a typo). I've modified the solution further following Charles' comment.

Comment: Great thanks, works fine and on a 3000x3000 and 5000x5000 Matrix it's on average just 10% slower than @Charles version, so very fast to me. Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[0,1,2,2,1,0;
5,6,3,0,1,2;
1,1,1,1,0,1];
%Do it column by column is easier
x=x';
rm=0;
while 1
    %fields to replace
    l=(x==0);
    %do nothing for the first row/column
    l(1,:)=0;
    rm2=sum(sum(l));
    if rm2==rm
        %nothing to do
        break;
    else
        rm=rm2;
    end
    %replace zeros
    x(l) = x(find(l)-1);
end
x=x';
```

Comment: It is a nearly vectorized solution. The loop is only required to deal with rows of zeros, if you have at most 5 consecutive zeros it will iterate 5 times. Check the performance, it's a very fast solution.

Comment: Daniel, thanks!, I've tried your solution and it is actually blazing fast, about 100 (!) times faster than applying the vectorized raw by row solution on a 1000X1000 Matrix and 20 times on a 2000X2000.

Comment: Hi @Daniel R I've noticed that when a row has 2 or more consecutive zeros at the beginning the code gets stucked, am I right?

Comment: @aldo: Are you using the current version of my code? Shortly after writing my answer I noticed a similar problem and updated it. The variables `rm` and `rm2` are new.

Comment: Your solution is the fastest with a very small number of zeros < 10% than it becomes slower and slower as we approach 50% so it's perfect fo <=3% zeros where it is twice as fast when compared to other solutions but less powerful when the average number of zeros is unknown. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a function I use for a similar problem for filling NaNs. This can probably be cutdown or sped up further - it's extracted from pre-existing code that has a bunch more functionality (forward/backward filling, maximum distance etc).

```
X = [
    0 1 2 2 1 0
    5 6 3 0 0 2
    1 1 1 1 0 1
    0 0 4 5 3 9
];

X(X == 0) = NaN;
Y = nanfill(X,2);
Y(isnan(Y)) = 0

function y = nanfill(x,dim)
if nargin < 2, dim = 1; end
if dim == 2, y = nanfill(x',1)'; return; end
i = find(~isnan(x(:)));
j = 1:size(x,1):numel(x);
j = j(ones(size(x,1),1),:);
ix = max(rep([1; i],diff([1; i; numel(x) + 1])),j(:));
y = reshape(x(ix),size(x));

function y = rep(x,times)
i = find(times);
if length(i) < length(times), x = x(i); times = times(i); end
i = cumsum([1; times(:)]);
j = zeros(i(end)-1,1);
j(i(1:end-1)) = 1;
y = x(cumsum(j));
```

Comment: This is probably more complex than needed for this problem - see my other answer.